# Powershell Add/Set-Content doesnt add variables

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script which supposed to create an other script.
My problem is the set or add-content doesn't add the variables from the section between @""@. The result is just blank, there is trace of variables in the output script.

```
$scriptPath = "C:\path_to_script2"
if (!(test-path $scriptPath))
{
# Step 1: Create script2.ps1 script

$scriptContent = @"

#PowerShell Start-Transcript
# ******************************************
$scriptName = "Create script2.ps1"
$logpath = "C:\Logs"
$scriptLog = "$logpath\$scriptName.log"
Start-Transcript -path $scriptLog -Debug -Confirm:$false
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
# ******************************************

#get hostname and set the final report filename
$computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$filename = ($computername+"_"+"battery-report.xml")

#Get Battery report
    Powercfg /batteryreport /output $reportfile /xml

#The target URL wit SAS Token
    $uri = "Token" #write only token                                                                      
#Define required Headers
    $headers = @{
        'x-ms-blob-type' = 'BlockBlob'
    }

#Uploading the report file...
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Headers $headers -InFile $reportfile 
        
#Removing the local the report file...
    remove-item $reportfile -Force

# PowerShell Stop-Transcript
# ******************************************
Stop-Transcript
# ******************************************
"@

$scriptPathFolder = "C:\Windows\Scripts"

# Create the script file
$scriptContent | Set-Content -Path $scriptPath
}
```

I am writing this in VS Code, tried to saving it in UTF-8 with BOM and Windows 1252 and added to the script with -encoding without success. Also tried the variables with '$variable', with a backslash before the variable and other apostrophe and quotation marks without success as well.

Comment: If you want the content of you here string to be taken literally you should use single quotes instead of doeble quotes. With double quotes variables will be replaced with their values. And when there is no value ....  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olaf is right. You have to use single quotes ' ' to preserve variables in the string.

```
$scriptPath = "C:\path_to_script2"
if (-not (Test-Path $scriptPath)) {
    # Step 1: Create script2.ps1 script

    $scriptContent = '
#PowerShell Start-Transcript
# ******************************************
$scriptName = "Create script2.ps1"
$logpath = "C:\Logs"
$scriptLog = "$logpath\$scriptName.log"
Start-Transcript -path $scriptLog -Debug -Confirm:$false
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
# ******************************************

#get hostname and set the final report filename
$computername = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$filename = ($computername+"_"+"battery-report.xml")

#Get Battery report
    Powercfg /batteryreport /output $reportfile /xml

#The target URL wit SAS Token
    $uri = "Token" #write only token                                                                      
#Define required Headers
    $headers = @{
        "x-ms-blob-typex" = "BlockBlobB"
    }

#Uploading the report file...
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Put -Headers $headers -InFile $reportfile 
        
#Removing the local the report file...
    remove-item $reportfile -Force

# PowerShell Stop-Transcript
# ******************************************
Stop-Transcript
# ******************************************'

    $scriptPathFolder = "C:\Windows\Scripts"

    # Create the script file
    $scriptContent | Set-Content -Path $scriptPath
}
```